# Не сохраняет доп. поле у товара в Мой Склад через JSON API

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Я отправляю товар для сохранения указывая доп. поле со значением. Товар существует и успешно сохраняется, но когда передаю доп поле, то возвращается ошибка.

```
array(1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["error"]=>
      string(188) "Ошибка сохранения дополнительного поля: идентификатор метаданных указывает на несуществующий объект"
      ["code"]=>
      int(14003)
      ["moreInfo"]=>
      string(82) "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc#обработка-ошибок-14003"
    }
  }
}
```

В качестве параметров я передаю в attributes:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(36) "3cc89dce-2d1f-11e9-9ff4-34e8001f9b34"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
  }
}
```

Само свойство я создал через API в общие справочники. Потом через настройку страницы на странице категории, я добавил это свойство к товару. Но почему-то не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста. Использую API 1.1

Comment: Можете добавить ваши запросы в формате CURL, в текущем виде не очень понятно что вы делаете не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке вы используете где-то неправильный идентификатор.

Насколько понял вы создали пользовательский справочник. А затем создали для товаров дополнительное поле, значением которого могут быть элементы этого справочника.

Чтобы передать дополнительное поле, нужно знать его id. Список дополнительных полей для товаров можно получить, запросив метаданные. `https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata`

В ответе приведено одно дополнительное поле типа пользовательский справочник.

`fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df` - id самого справочника

`bf66de8e-c54d-11e8-9109-f8fc002396e4` - id дополнительного поля

```
{  
  "meta":{  
    "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata",
    "mediaType":"application/json"
  },
  "attributes":[  
    {  
      "meta":{  
        "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata/attributes/bf66de8e-c54d-11e8-9109-f8fc002396e4",
        "type":"attributemetadata",
        "mediaType":"application/json"
      },
      "customEntityMeta":{  
        "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/companysettings/metadata/customEntities/fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df",
        "type":"customentitymetadata",
        "mediaType":"application/json"
      },
      "id":"bf66de8e-c54d-11e8-9109-f8fc002396e4",
      "name":"Станция Метро",
      "type":"customentity",
      "required":false
    }
  ],
  "priceTypes":[  
    {  
      "name":"Цена продажи"
    }
  ],
  "createShared":false
}
```

При редактировании товара значение дополнительного поля - это элемент пользовательского справочника. Получить список элементов пользовательского справочника `https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customentity/fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df`.

`c5750358-67f3-4790-a1a4-c852cf2324ac` - id элемента пользовательского справочника

```
{  
  "context":{  
    "employee":{  
      "meta":{  
        "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/context/employee",
        "metadataHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/employee/metadata",
        "type":"employee",
        "mediaType":"application/json"
      }
    }
  },
  "meta":{  
    "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customentity/fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df",
    "type":"customentity",
    "mediaType":"application/json",
    "uuidHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#custom_fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df",
    "size":22,
    "limit":25,
    "offset":0
  },
  "rows":[  
    ...
    {  
      "meta":{  
        "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customentity/fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df/c5750358-67f3-4790-a1a4-c852cf2324ac",
        "metadataHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/companysettings/metadata/customEntities/fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df",
        "type":"customentity",
        "mediaType":"application/json",
        "uuidHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#custom_fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df/edit?id=c5750358-67f3-4790-a1a4-c852cf2324ac"
      },
      "id":"c5750358-67f3-4790-a1a4-c852cf2324ac",
      "accountId":"45eb22e0-0e7b-11e2-1c31-3c4a92f3a0a7",
      "updated":"2012-01-27 17:32:51",
      "name":"Пушкинская",
      "externalCode":"gcKbY3Liju2WnuaaXX-IB3"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Наконец, собираем все вместе, чтобы обновить товар.
PUT `https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/d6be6595-724d-4bab-a532-36c6908e0643`

```
{  
  "attributes":[  
    {  
      "meta":{  
        "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata/attributes/bf66de8e-c54d-11e8-9109-f8fc002396e4",
        "type":"attributemetadata",
        "mediaType":"application/json"
      },
      "id":"bf66de8e-c54d-11e8-9109-f8fc002396e4",
      "value":{  
        "meta":{  
          "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customentity/fdc2f12e-75e4-4beb-8fd6-f8395961a4df/c5750358-67f3-4790-a1a4-c852cf2324ac",
          "type":"customentity",
          "mediaType":"application/json"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно спасибо!